# What do these wirless setting for a keyboard indicate in Ubuntu settings?

Tags: keyboard, settings, wireless-keyboards

[image]

The above image is from the Ubuntu Settings page for Power. Under devices it shows a wireless keyboard with a 60% green bar. What does it indicate ? It certainly is not the power left in the keyboard because a new or a old battery still shows the same green bar at 60%.
I am actually looking for a soln to connectivity issues with my wireless keyboard. My keyboard on a random basis becomes unresponsive and starts dropping characters when typing. Many a times after a long typing gap when I start typing, the characters take a few seconds to show up on the monitor instead of immediately as I start typing and sometimes the first few characters are just dropped.
eg If I intend to type "The quick brown fox" it will start printing the chars from
"e quick brown fox". Any way to improve the response between the keyboard the unifying receiver ? I have a K270 keyboard from Logitech.
Any solns from anyone having similar issues ?

Comment: Do you have a Bluetooth dongle in this machine?  I had to upgrade my Bluetooth dongle to version 4 or better to get it to stop interfering with the Logitech Unified receiver. BTW it is always nice and often needed to say what the version of Ubuntu it is.

Comment: @David I do have a wireless card in my desktop for wifi and bluetooth on the same card. Bluetooth is 95% kept in the off mode and switched on when required. Keyboard issues are all the time. OS is Ubuntu 20.04 LTS. And I apply all Ubuntu updates as when they are published. The network card drivers published are normally for Windows and MAC. For Linux the hardware just runs out the box. Never applied a driver but will still go back and check if the TPlInk has a bluetooth driver for Linux that I need to apply.

Comment: You may want to contact Logitech https://www.logitech.com/en-gb/products/keyboards/k270-unifying-wireless.html and ask them if the answer @Nate T is giving can be the issue. Logitech says they only have software for Windows. I did find it interesting they use the same frequency as wireless for their keyboards.

Comment: Getting in touch with them is a last resort. Wanted to check if this a common problem and a if there is a solution to it. If what @nate t says is correct then I guess Logitech will also put their hands up and say it is working as designed. The problem is we cannot put the receiver on the USB hub also but it has to be on the motherboard directly otherwise it doesn't work. I thought it might be the distance from the receiver.

Comment: Good luck my Logitech K400 plus never goes to sleep.

Comment: I have K270 keyboard, but with nano receiver. It wake up without a delay.

Comment: @pasmanpasmański apart from the no delay error do you have any issues with characters not being captured on a random basis even though you have been using the keyboard continuously?

Comment: No. No dropped chars in terminal , libreoffice.

Comment: Check that the firmware in the USB dongle is current. You'll need Windows to be able to run the utility to update it. If you have a choice, put the dongle into a USB2 port connected to the motherboard.

Answer (score 0):

As far as the connectivity, t is the timeout that is stopping it. It is the sleep timeout, and it is intended behavior.

After 10 sec without a key press, it shuts down into sleep mode. To get it to wake, you just press another key, but it takes a full 3 seconds, usually, to power back on.

This is all to save on battery power. Changing the behavior depends on the model of keyboard. Some are configurable, and others are not. You will need to research your device online.